# Perform initial loading in node in hasAndBelongsToMany relation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, has-and-belongs-to-many

How I can make a initial load data in a hasAndBelongsToMany relation ?

**Example:**

```
Model Product
{
idProduct,
Description
(..)
}

Model Order
{
idOrder,
Date
(...)
}
```

**In the swagger have:**

```
PUT: /order/{id}/product/rel/{fk}
{
  "id": "string",
  "orderId": "string",
  "productId": "string"
}
```

But in I dont know how I can make this my node boot script (how method I can call to make this) ...

I know how to insert orders, insert products but I dont know how I can "link" one or more products in one or more orders.

I see in other links the `"Order.Product.link({id1: val1, id2: val2})"` but dont work in node...

Answer (score 0):

To create a new link, you need to obtain an instance of the source model (Order) first, and then call relation method `add` to establish the relation with the target model (Product).

```
const order = await Order.findById(orderId);
await order.products.add(productId);
```

If you are adding products while creating a new order:

```
const order = await Order.create({/* order data */});
await order.products.add(productId);
```

Here is a callback based version in case you are not using async functions or Promises yet:

```
Order.findById(orderId, function(err, order) {
  if (err) // handle the error

  order.products.add(productId, function(err) {

    if (err) // handle the error
    // done
  });
});
```